# Template function definition extensions in Clang++

Tags: c++, templates, clang, c++20

It turns out that Clang compiler accepts certain non-standard variants of template function definitions.

In this example

```
#include <iostream>

template<> //#1
void foo(auto x) { std::cout << x; };

template<> //#2
void foo(int) requires(false) { std::cout << "int"; };

int main() { foo(1); }
```

#1 is a definition of new template function in C++20 style (with `auto` keyword), however it is not a template specialization, so the begging with `template<>` is not-standard.

And #2 is a full specialization, so it is not-template function by itself, and `requires` section is not expected here, but accepted (and ignored) by Clang.

The program prints `int`, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xTzP177Gd

Are these simply Clang bugs, or they are some language extensions that can be used with a purpose?

Comment: Even if it's an extension, `-pedantic-errors` should've disabled it. I suggest filing a bug.

Comment: Good idea, reported Clang bug: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51831